# Firebird can't save to blob column because string literal too big

Tags: ruby, firebird

I have a table that save various input from users. In one column we write a giant json string produced a step by step wizard. This column is defined as a blob sub_type 1 with the utf-8 charset.

Now I when I want to save the last step I get this error:

> String literal with 16538 characters exceeds the maximum length of 16383 characters for the UTF8 character set

This happens online with my Rails server and also with my db admin tool (DBeaver).

According to [this Link](http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/Maximum-length-of-string-literals-td4640262.html) there is a max length of a string literal. How do I save a string longer than this limit in a blob field?

This would be the statement:

```
UPDATE "TABLE_WITH_JSON_STRING_FIELD" SET
    "JSON_FIELD" = '{"allgemeine_fragen":{"vorname":"John","nachname":"Smith","geburtstag":"01.01.1900","telefon":"0049 123 456 789 0","email":"test@tst.com","anzahl_kinder":"","beruf":"","groesse_cm":"","groesse_ft_in":"","gewicht_kg":"","gewicht_lb":"","bmi":"","kur":[{"jahr":"Jul 2015","klinikname":"test","ort":"baden baden"},{"jahr":"May 2013","klinikname":"test 2","ort":"test 2"}],"hobbies":"","im_ruhestand":"0"},"familienanamnese":{"vater_sonstiges":"","vater_anderes_karzinom":"","brueder_sonstiges":"","brueder_anderes_karzinom":"","sonstige_verwandte_sonstiges":"","sonstige_verwandte_anderes_karzinom":"","mutter_sonstiges":"","mutter_anderes_karzinom":"","schwestern_sonstiges":"","schwestern_anderes_karzinom":"","vater_schlaganfall":"0","vater_herzinfarkt":"0","vater_koronare_herzerkrankung":"0","vater_diabetes":"0","vater_bluthochdruck":"0","vater_darmerkrankungen":"0","vater_adipositas_fettleibigkeit":"0","vater_erhoehte_fettwerte":"0","vater_psych_erkrankung":"0","vater_alzheimer_demenz":"0","vater_thrombose_lungenembolie":"0","vater_osteoporose":"0","vater_blasenkarzinom":"0","vater_lungenkarzinom":"0","vater_dickdarmkarzinom":"0","vater_melanom":"0","vater_prostatakarzinom":"0","vater_hodenkarzinom":"0","brueder_schlaganfall":"0","brueder_herzinfarkt":"0","brueder_koronare_herzerkrankung":"0","brueder_diabetes":"0","brueder_bluthochdruck":"0","brueder_darmerkrankungen":"0","brueder_adipositas_fettleibigkeit":"0","brueder_erhoehte_fettwerte":"0","brueder_psych_erkrankung":"0","brueder_alzheimer_demenz":"0","brueder_thrombose_lungenembolie":"0","brueder_osteoporose":"0","brueder_blasenkarzinom":"0","brueder_lungenkarzinom":"0","brueder_dickdarmkarzinom":"0","brueder_melanom":"0","brueder_prostatakarzinom":"0","brueder_hodenkarzinom":"0","sonstige_verwandte_schlaganfall":"0","sonstige_verwandte_herzinfarkt":"0","sonstige_verwandte_koronare_herzerkrankung":"0","sonstige_verwandte_diabetes":"0","sonstige_verwandte_bluthochdruck":"0","sonstige_verwandte_darmerkrankungen":"0","sonstige_verwandte_adipositas_fettleibigkeit":"0","sonstige_verwandte_erhoehte_fettwerte":"0","sonstige_verwandte_psych_erkrankung":"0","sonstige_verwandte_alzheimer_demenz":"0","sonstige_verwandte_thrombose_lungenembolie":"0","sonstige_verwandte_osteoporose":"0","sonstige_verwandte_blasenkarzinom":"0","sonstige_verwandte_lungenkarzinom":"0","sonstige_verwandte_dickdarmkarzinom":"0","sonstige_verwandte_melanom":"0","sonstige_verwandte_prostatakarzinom":"0","sonstige_verwandte_hodenkarzinom":"0","sonstige_verwandte_mammakarzinom":"0","sonstige_verwandte_ovarialkarzinom":"0","sonstige_verwandte_zervixkarzinom":"0","mutter_schlaganfall":"0","mutter_herzinfarkt":"0","mutter_koronare_herzerkrankung":"0","mutter_diabetes":"0","mutter_bluthochdruck":"0","mutter_darmerkrankungen":"0","mutter_adipositas_fettleibigkeit":"0","mutter_erhoehte_fettwerte":"0","mutter_psych_erkrankung":"0","mutter_alzheimer_demenz":"0","mutter_thrombose_lungenembolie":"0","mutter_osteoporose":"0","mutter_blasenkarzinom":"0","mutter_lungenkarzinom":"0","mutter_dickdarmkarzinom":"0","mutter_melanom":"0","mutter_mammakarzinom":"0","mutter_ovarialkarzinom":"0","mutter_zervixkarzinom":"0","schwestern_schlaganfall":"0","schwestern_herzinfarkt":"0","schwestern_koronare_herzerkrankung":"0","schwestern_diabetes":"0","schwestern_bluthochdruck":"0","schwestern_darmerkrankungen":"0","schwestern_adipositas_fettleibigkeit":"0","schwestern_erhoehte_fettwerte":"0","schwestern_psych_erkrankung":"0","schwestern_alzheimer_demenz":"0","schwestern_thrombose_lungenembolie":"0","schwestern_osteoporose":"0","schwestern_blasenkarzinom":"0","schwestern_lungenkarzinom":"0","schwestern_dickdarmkarzinom":"0","schwestern_melanom":"0","schwestern_mammakarzinom":"0","schwestern_ovarialkarzinom":"0","schwestern_zervixkarzinom":"0"},"medikamente_supplemente":{"medikament":[{"name":"","dosierung":"","morgens":"","mittags":"","abends":"","nachts":"","beibedarf":"","seitwann":""}],"supplement":[{"name":"","dosierung":"","morgens":"","mittags":"","abends":"","nachts":"","beibedarf":"","seitwann":""}]},"allergien_unvertraeglichkeiten":{"unvertraeglichkeiten_nahrung_sonstige":"","umweltallergene_sonstige":"","medikamentenallergie":"","unvertraeglichkeiten_sonstige":"","medikamentenallergie_ja":"0"},"ernaehrungsanamnese":{"trinkverhalten_alkohol_name":"","trinkverhalten_trinken_sonstiges_name":"","ernaehrungsprofil_fruehstueck_was":"","ernaehrungsprofil_mittagessen_was":"","ernaehrungsprofil_abendessen_was":"","ernaehrungsprofil_zwischenmahlzeiten_was":"","ernaehrungsanamnese_bemerkungen":"","rauchverhalten_rauchen_beginn":"","rauchverhalten_rauchen_ende":"","rauchverhalten_rauchen_zigaretten_tag":"","rauchverhalten_rauchen_packyears":"","sucht_sonstiges":"","rauchverhalten_rauchen_zigaretten":"0","rauchverhalten_rauchen_e_zigarette":"0","rauchverhalten_rauchen_pfeife":"0","rauchverhalten_rauchen_zigarre":"0","rauchverhalten_rauchen_shisha":"0","sucht_alkohol":"0","sucht_medikamente":"0","sucht_drogen":"0","ernaehrungsberatung_gewuenscht":null},"darmgesundheit":{"darm_diagnosen_sonstiges":"","stuhlgang_rhythmus_pro_tag":"","stuhlgang_rhythmus_pro_woche":"","darm_beschwerden_symptome_sonstige":"","darmgesundheit_bemerkungen":"","gastroskopie_jahr":"","gastroskopie_wiederholung_geplant":"","gastroskopie_befund":"","koloskopie_jahr":"","koloskopie_wiederholung_geplant":"","koloskopie_befund":"","kapselendoskopie_jahr":"","kapselendoskopie_wiederholung_geplant":"","kapselendoskopie_befund":"","sonographie_abdomens_jahr":"","sonographie_abdomens_wiederholung_geplant":"","sonographie_abdomens_befund":"","darmgesundheit_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","klinik":"","behandlung":""}],"helicobacter":"0","reflux":"0","refluxoesophagitis":"0","gastritis":"0","morbus_crohn":"0","colitis_ulcerosa":"0","diverticulitis":"0","haemorrhoiden":"0","koloskopie_gewuenscht":null,"gastroskopie_gewuenscht":null,"kapselendoskopie_gewuenscht":null,"sonographie_abdomens_gewuenscht":null},"herzkreislaufmedizin":{"hypotonie_seit":"","bluthochdruck_seit":"","herzinfarkt_wann":"","herzinfarkt_wo":"","herzinfarkt_befund":"","herzkreislauf_diagnosen_sonstiges":"","herzkreislauf_weitere_beschwerden_symptome":"","herzkreislaufmedizin_bemerkungen":"","kardiocheck_wann":"","blutdruck":[{"datum":"","morgens":"","mittags":"","abends":""}],"kardio_ct_wann":"","kardio_ct_wo":"","kardio_ct_befund":"","herzkreislauf_sonstige_diagnostik":"","bypass_operation_wann":"","bypass_operation_wo":"","bypass_operation_befund":"","klappen_operation_wann":"","klappen_operation_wo":"","klappen_operation_befund":"","herzkatheter_wann":"","herzkatheter_wo":"","herzkatheter_befund":"","herzkreislauf_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","klinik":"","behandlung":""}],"hypotonie":"0","bluthochdruck":"0","koronare_herzkrankheit":"0","herzinsuffizienz":"0","synkope":"0","trombose_lungenembolie":"0","vorhofflimmern":"0","herzrhythmusstoerungen":"0","pavk":"0","herzinfarkt":"0","beschwerde_herzstolpern_rhythmusstoerungen":"0","beschwerde_luftnot_bei_belastung":"0","luftnot_in_ruhe":"0","beschwerde_angina_pectoris":"0","schwindel":"0","geschwollene_beine":"0","kardiocheck":"0","kardio_ct":"0","bypass_operation":"0","klappen_operation":"0","herzkatheter":"0","stent":"0","herzschrittmacher":"0","kardio_check_gewuenscht":null},"stoffwechsel":{"stoffwechsel_beschwerden_symptome":"","stoffwechsel_bemerkungen":"","sono_schilddrüse_jahr":"","sono_schilddrüse_wiederholung_geplant":"","sono_schilddrüse_befund":"","stoffwechsel_diagnostik":"","stoffwechsel_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"diabetes_typ_1":"0","diabetes_typ_2":"0","schilddruesenueberfunktion":"0","schilddruesenunterfunktion":"0","erhoehte_blutfette":"0","hypercholesterinaemie":"0","hypertriglyceridaemie":"0","fettleber":"0","sono_schilddruese_gewuenscht":null},"augenheilkunde":{"augenheilkunde_beschwerden_symptome":"","augenheilkunde_bemerkungen":"","augenheilkunde_diagnostik":"","augenheilkunde_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"diabetische_retinopathie":"0","hypertensive_retinopathie":"0","erhoehter_augeninnendruck":"0","linsentruebung":"0","kurzsichtigkeit":"0","weitsichtigkeit":"0","alterssichtigkeit":"0","sehhilfe_brille":"0","sehhilfe_linsen":"0","augen_vorsorgediagnostik_gewuenscht":null},"zahnheilkunde":{"zahnheilkunde_diagnosen":"","zahnheilkunde_beschwerden_symptome":"","zahnheilkunde_bemerkungen":"","letzte_zahnaerztliche_kontrolle":"","zahnheilkunde_diagnostik":"","zahnheilkunde_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"zahnfleischbluten_entzuendungen":"0","zaehneknirschen":"0","zahnfleischrueckgang":"0","problem_kiefergelenk":"0","fehlbiss":"0","zahnersatz":"0","implantate":"0","fuellungen":"0","fuellung_gold":"0","fuellung_amalgam":"0","fuellung_kunststoff":"0","keramikkronen":"0","wurzelbehandlungen":"0","zahnregulierungen_kieferorthopaed":"0","zahnuntersuchung_gewuenscht":null,"prof_zahnreinigung_gewuenscht":null,"bleaching_gewuenscht":null},"atemwege_hno":{"atemwege_hno_beschwerden_symptome":"","atemwege_hno_bemerkungen":"","atemwege_hno_diagnostik":"","atemwege_hno_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"chron_sinusitis_tinnitus":"0","copd_chronische_bronchitis":"0","asthma_bronchiale":"0","schwerhoerigkeit":"0","tinnitus":"0","halsschmerzen":"0","chron_schnupfen":"0","geschwollene_lymphknoten":"0","riechstoerung":"0","schwindel":"0","hno_untersuchung_gewuenscht":null,"lungen_untersuchung_gewuenscht":null},"sportmedizin_orthopaedie":{"sport_zeit_pro_woche":"","form_bewegung_sport":"","schulterschmerzen_sonstiges":"","rueckenschmerzen_sonstiges":"","tennisellenbogen_text":"","hand_sonstiges":"","huefte_sonstiges":"","knie_sonstiges":"","fuesse_einlagen":"","mittelfussbruch_ermuedungsbruch":"","sprunggelenk_fuesse_sonstiges":"","knochenbrueche_wann":"","knochenbrueche_lokalisation":"","sportunfaelle_wann":"","sportunfaelle_therapie":"","trainingstherapie_gewunscht_anzahl":null,"trainingstherapie_gewunscht_sonstige_text":null,"herzkreislaufmedizin_bemerkungen":"","aktuelle_beschwerden":"","durchgefuehrte_orthop_therapien":"","cortison_injektionen_wann":"","cortison_injektionen_wo":"","stosswellentherapie_wann":"","stosswellentherapie_wo":"","physiotherapie":"","tcm":"","med_trainingstherapie":"","magnetfeldtherapie":"","medikamente":"","sonstige":"","schulterschmerzen":"0","schulter_schleimbeutel":"0","schulter_verkalkung":"0","schulter_arthrose":"0","rueckenschmerzen":"0","halswirbelsaeule":"0","halswirbelsaeule_bandscheibenvorfall":"0","halswirbelsaeule_op":"0","brustwirbelsaeule":"0","brustwirbelsaeule_bandscheibenvorfall":"0","brustwirbelsaeule_op":"0","lendenwirbelsaeule":"0","lendenwirbelsaeule_bandscheibenvorfall":"0","lendenwirbelsaeule_op":"0","iliosakralgelenk":"0","iliosakralgelenk_bandscheibenvorfall":"0","iliosakralgelenk_op":"0","tennisellenbogen":"0","hand":"0","ganglion":"0","fingerarthrosen":"0","karpaltunnelsyndrom":"0","huefte":"0","hueftarthrose":"0","huefte_schleimbeutel":"0","leistenschmerzen":"0","knie":"0","meniskusschaden":"0","knorpelschaeden":"0","kreuzbandverletzung":"0","kniearthrose":"0","kniegelenkserguss":"0","sprunggelenk_fuesse":"0","sprunggelenk_fuesse_arthrose":"0","baenderrisse":"0","achillessehnenbeschwerden":"0","spreiz_send_plattfuesse":"0","fersensporn":"0","muskelverletzungen":"0","muskelkraempfe":"0","sehnenverletzungen":"0","knochenbrueche":"0","knochenbrueche_op":"0","osteoporose":"0","rachitis":"0","vitamin_d_mangel":"0","rheuma":"0","sportunfaelle":"0","trainingstherapie_gewunscht_fahrrad":null,"trainingstherapie_gewunscht_golf":null,"trainingstherapie_gewunscht_sonstige":null,"cortison_injektionen":"0","stosswellentherapie":"0","orthopaedische_untersuchung_gewuenscht":null,"sportmedizinische_untersuchung_gewuenscht":null,"trainingstherapie_gewunscht":null,"physiotherapie_gewunscht":null,"osteopathie_gewunscht":null,"kaeltetherapie_gewuenscht":null,"hoehentherapie_gewuenscht":null,"trainingstherapie_gewunscht_radio":null},"nerven_neurologie":{"nerven_neurologie_diagnosen_sonstiges":"","nerven_neurologie_beschwerden_symptome":"","nerven_neurologie_bemerkungen":"","dopplersono_carotiden_jahr":"","dopplersono_carotiden_wiederholung_geplant":"","dopplersono_carotiden_befund":"","nerven_neurologie_diagnostik":"","nerven_neurologie_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"schlaganfall":"0","polyneuropathie":"0","multiple_sklerose":"0","morbus_parkinson":"0","demenz":"0","migraene":"0","kopfschmerzen":"0","epilepsie":"0","schwindel":"0","taubheit":"0","kraftverlust":"0","laehmungen":"0","demenzcheck_gewuenscht":null,"neurologische_untersuchung_gewuenscht":null,"dopplersono_carotiden_gewuenscht":null},"schmerz":{"sonstiger_schmerz":"0","keine_schmerzen":"0"},"frauengesundheit_gynaekologie":{"geburten_anzahl":"","fehlgeburten_anzahl":"","zyklusanamnese_sonstiges":"","gynaekologie_bemerkungen":"","brustkrebs_screening_jahr":"","brustkrebs_screening_wiederholung_geplant":"","brustkrebs_screening_befund":"","gynaekologischer_check_jahr":"","gynaekologischer_check_wiederholung_geplant":"","gynaekologischer_check_befund":"","gynaekologie_diagnostik":"","gynaekologie_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"geburt":"0","fehlgeburt":"0","sectio":"0","dammriss_dammschnitt":"0","brustkrebs":"0","gebaermutterkrebs":"0","eierstockkrebs":"0","brustkrebs_screening_gewuenscht":null,"gynaekologischer_check_gewuenscht":null,"hormonsprechstunde_gewuenscht":null},"nephrologie_urogenitaltrakt_female":{"nephrologie_urogenitaltrakt_diagnosen":"","haeufiges_wasserlassen_wie_oft":"","naechtliches_wasserlassen_wie_oft":"","nephrologie_urogenitaltrakt_beschwerden_symptome":"","nephrologie_urogenitaltrakt_bemerkungen":"","nephrologie_urogenitaltrakt_diagnostik":"","nephrologie_urogenitaltrakt_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"niereninsuffizienz":"0","nierensteine":"0","chronische_harnwegsinfekte":"0","urininkontinenz":"0","abgeschwaechter_harnstrahl":"0","schmerzen_wasserlassen":"0","haeufiges_wasserlassen":"0","naechtliches_wasserlassen":"0"},"psyche":{"psyche_diagnosen":"","psyche_beschwerden_symptome":"","psyche_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"psyche_bemerkungen":"","psyche_froehlich":"0","psyche_gluecklich":"0","psyche_ausgeglichen":"0","psyche_traurig":"0","psyche_depressiv":"0","psyche_aggressiv":"0","psyche_einsam":"0","erschoepft":"0","psychologisches_gespraech_gewuenscht":null,"coaching_beratung_gewuenscht":null},"dermatologie_aesthetik":{"dermatologie_aesthetik_bemerkungen":"","dermatologie_aesthetik_beschwerden_symptome":"","dermatologie_aesthetik_wuensche":"","hautkrebsscreening_jahr":"","hautkrebsscreeninge_wiederholung_geplant":"","hautkrebsscreening_befund":"","dermatologie_aesthetik_diagnostik":"","dermatologie_aesthetik_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"psoriasis":"0","neurodermitis":"0","basaliom":"0","melanom":"0","dermatologische_diagnostik_gewuenscht":null},"schlafmedizin":{"schlafmedizin_schlafqualitaet":"1","schlafmedizin_bemerkungen":"","schlafmedizin_wuensche":"","schlafmedizin_schlaflabor_untersuchung_wann":"","schlafmedizin_diagnostik":"","schlafmedizin_op_therapie":[{"jahr":"","ort":"","befund":""}],"schlafmedizin_schlafapnoe":"0","schlafmedizin_beatmungsgeraet":"0","schlafmedizin_unterkieferprotrusionsschiene":"0","schlafmedizin_einschlafstoerungen":"0","schlafmedizin_durchschlafstoerungen":"0","schlafmedizin_naechtliches_wasserlassen":"0","schlafmedizin_schnarchen":"0","schlafmedizin_apnoe":"0","schlafmedizin_lumbalgie":"0","schlafmedizin_muskelkraempfe":"0","schlafmedizin_morgenmuedigkeit":"0","schlafmedizin_zappelbeine":"0","schlafmedizin_sekundenschlaf":"0","schlafmedizin_nachtschweiss":"0","schlaflaboruntersuchung_gewuenscht":null,"schlafmedizinische_beratung_gewuenscht":null},"infektion_reisemedizin_impfung":{"infektionen_chronisch_sonstige":"","infektions_reisemedizin_impfung_bemerkungen":"","infektions_reisemedizin_impfung_wuensche":"","impfungen_influenza_letzte_impfung":"","impfungen_sonstige":"","herpes":"0","infektionen_hepatitis_b":"0","infektionen_hepatitis_c":"0","infektionen_hiv":"0","infektionen_tuberkulose":"0","infektionen_infektioese_durchfaelle":"0","infektionen_resistente_keime":"0","malaria":"0"},"nephrologie_urogenitaltrakt":{"urogloische_diagnostik_gewuenscht":null},"gewuenschte_diagnostik_therapie":{"trainingstherapie_gewunscht_anzahl":"","trainingstherapie_gewun2018-11-27T09:06:57.467671307Z scht_sonstige_text":"","wuensche_bemerkungen":"","trainingstherapie_gewunscht_fahrrad":"0","trainingstherapie_gewunscht_golf":"0","trainingstherapie_gewunscht_sonstige":"0"}}'
WHERE
    "TABLE_WITH_JSON_STRING_FIELD"."ID" = 129444104;
```

Comment: Have you tried using parameters instead?

Comment: you have to use parameters: http://bobby-tables.com

Comment: Here is how it looks on Ruby: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10181301/976391

Comment: @engineersmnky that is not a good way to do it: there is another maximum limit on the statement length in whole. You would trade one limit for another. In brief, one should not pass data as text literals, stressing SQL parser, inflating traffic and opening possibilities for errors like type mismatches and SQL injections. Program is program and data is data. SQL request is program, ideally it is to be compiled once and then executed against different - and type-checked - data. That is what SQL query preparation and data parameters are for.

Comment: for firebird 2.5 blob fields there's no limit for 16Kb  UTF8 chars (read this man https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-bnrytypes.html) 
it's just segment size .
limit for firebird blob filed in Unicode is near  2^30 chars (https://firebirdsql.org/manual/migration-mssql-data-types.html)
I've successfully tested your update statement with Ibexpert 
for this structure 

CREATE TABLE TABLE_WITH_JSON_STRING_FIELD (
    ID          INTEGER NOT NULL,
    JSON_FIELD  BLOB SUB_TYPE 1 SEGMENT SIZE 32762 CHARACTER SET UTF8
);

Comment: In Rails I call the update with the update_attributes method `obj.update_attributes(patient_json: string)` And this creates the update statement above.Should I call a different method to get past this limitation?

Comment: that is a question of Ruby libraries used there in stack, their capabilities, etc. There are examples on B.T. site but I don't know if they are about your libraries or some other Ruby libs. Proper SQL way - both safer and faster - is not making ad hoc brand new SQL text request every now and then, but making a "standard" query for a typical change, preparing it once and forever, and then just refilling parameters data without changing and re-compiling the query itself. In one my legacy app the speedup seemed like 2-3 times. I don't know if the libs you choose in Ruby are capable of it or not.

Comment: you can also save JSON ZIP or JSON GZ, not plain text JSON. It would push the limit to a degree, unless it would be zip/gz binary data size, that would exceed sting HEX literal max length. Still, using literals for arbitrary length data is not lucky choice, even if would to a degree stretch the limits, but then storing packed texts instead of redundant JSON would perhaps be better for both disk I/O and database file size even when you later would switch to using parameters.

Comment: Check this also: https://github.com/petdance/bobby-tables/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+ruby

Comment: @KonstantinStreletsky The problem here is that the driver used will not populate a blob itself, but instead produces a literal string with the value to leave populating the blob to Firebird. String literals have a limited size (iirc 64KB in Firebird 3, which limits it to 16383 characters UTF8). Also note that segment sizes are irrelevant for most applications of Firebird; they are a historical holdover that are (or: should be) only relevant for applications using embedded SQL using GPRE.

Comment: Shimu, I think you hit an implementation gotcha of the driver you're using. You might want to ask the maintainer of that driver to find out if there is another way or not.

Comment: Thanks for all the hints. I ended up zipping the string and sending the data this way. I know, I won't be safe for ever, but I am reasonable far away from the limits for now. A short question though: Where can I find some docu about parameterized statements? A link would be nice :-)